# How can I fix a Python circular import problem?

Tags: python, pygame

I have 3 python files: main.py, settings.py and classes.py

main.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from classes import *
from settings import *

pg.font.init()
HEALTH_FONT = pg.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)

pg.display.set_caption("Testa Game")
ground_surface = pg.image.load('graphics/ground.png').convert()
BG_COLOR = (0, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

run = True
while run == True:
      clock = pg.time.Clock()
      for event in pg.event.get():
          if event.type == pg.QUIT:
             pg.quit()
             exit()
    
clock.tick(FPS)
keys_pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
health_text = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health: " + str(class_type.health), 1, BLACK)
WIN.fill(BG_COLOR)
WIN.blit(class_type.karakter_surface, (class_type.karakter.x, class_type.karakter.y))
WIN.blit(ground_surface, (0, 350))
WIN.blit(health_text, (10, 10))
karakter_moving(keys_pressed, class_type.karakter)

pg.display.flip()
```

settings.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from classes import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
class_type = death_mage
FPS = 60
def karakter_moving(keys_pressed, karakter):
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_w] and karakter.y - class_type.speed > 0:
       karakter.y -= class_type.speed
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_s] and karakter.y + class_type.speed  + karakter.height < HEIGHT - 5: 
       karakter.y += class_type.speed
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_a] and karakter.x - class_type.speed > 0: #LEFT
       karakter.x -= class_type.speed
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_d] and karakter.x + class_type.speed  + karakter.width < WIDTH:
       karakter.x += class_type.speed
```

classes.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import WIN
pg.init()

def fire_ball():
    fireball = []
    maxFireBall = 3
    manacost = 1
    color = 'ORANGE'
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE and len(fireball) < maxFireBall:
                dmFireBall = pg.Rect(
                death_mage.karakter.x + death_mage.karakter.width, death_mage.karakter.y + death_mage.karakter.height//2 - 2, 10, 5)
                fireball.append(dmFireBall)
                death_mage.mana -= manacost
        pg.draw.rect(WIN, color, fireball)

class death_mage:
      KARAKTER_WIDTH, KARAKTER_HEIGHT = 60, 85
      karakter = pg.Rect(400, 200, KARAKTER_WIDTH, KARAKTER_HEIGHT)
      karakter_surface = pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load('Assets/death_mage.png'), (KARAKTER_WIDTH, KARAKTER_HEIGHT))
      health = 10
      mana = 5
      attack = 1
      speed = 2
      attack_speed = 1
      crit_rate = 0
      crit_damage = 0
```

Error message:

```
"settings.py", line 12, in <module>
    class_type = death_mage
NameError: name 'death_mage' is not defined
```

or if settings.py: from classes import death_mage

```
"settings.py", line 3, in <module>
    from classes import death_mage
ImportError: cannot import name 'death_mage' from partially initialized module 'classes' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How can I remedy this?
Thanks to helping me

Comment: It's not clear why `karakter_moving` should be part of `settings.py`, since it's not actually a "setting," but if you really want to do that, pass `class_type` as a parameter to `karakter_moving`.  That eliminates the dependency.

Comment: I've found it helpful to mentally organize my modules into "layers", and make sure that a module only imports other modules that are lower than itself.

Answer (score -3):

One of your modules has got no urls.py